# Positive homogeneous

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, multivariable-calculus

**Question:** A set $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is called a cone in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $x \in X$ implies $tx ∈ X$ for every $t\in\mathbb{R}_+$. Given a cone $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, a function $f\colon X \to\mathbb{R}$ is said to be positive homogeneous of degree $k \in\mathbb{R}$ if $f(tx) = t^kf(x)$ for every $x \in X$ and every $t\in\mathbb{R}_{++}$.

1) Let $X$ be the interior of a cone in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f\colon X \to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on $X$. Show that $f$ is positive homogeneous of degree $k$ iff  $kf(x) = Df(x)\cdot x$ for every $x ∈ X$.
(Notation: $Df(x)$ is derivative of $f$ at $x$ and $Df(x)\cdot x$ is (unitary) inner product of $Df(x)$ and $x$).

2) Let $X$ be the interior of a cone in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let f: X $\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on X. Show that, if f is positive homogeneous of degree k, then the partial derivative $D_if$ is homogeneous of degree $k-1$ for $i=1,...,n$ .

**Source:** From the question paper of an exam conducted in 2005.

**my try**:
**EDIT:** *It has been 2 days since I asked this question. Please, anybody, help me..*

I got stuck in between.
First part:
Given: f(tx)=$t^k$f(x)

**I just realised $Df(x)$ is differentiation of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$ and not $t$. This means the following solution(my try) is completely wrong. But earlier also when I tried to solve it by differentiating it with respect to $x$ I was not getting anywhere. $\mathbf{Please\, help}$.**

differentiating wrt t

$\implies$ $xDf(tx)=kt^{k-1}f(x)$

setting t=1

$\implies xDf(x)=kf(x)$

to prove: $<Df(x),x>=kf(x)$

LHS=$<(k/x)f(x) , x>$

=$k<f(x)/x  ,  x>$

Now I am stuck.

Please help...

Comment: not much. I got stuck in between.
First part:
Given: f(tx)=$t^k$f(x) 
$\implies$ Df(tx)=$t^{k-1}$Df(x)...

to prove: <Df(x),x>=kf(x)
LHS=<Df(tx)/$t^{k-1}$ , x>
   =(1/$t^{k-1}$)<Df(tx) , x> 
   =(1/$t^k$)<Df(tx) , tx> 
   =(1/$t^k$)<Df(y) , y>  ; here replacing tx by y....
  Now I am stuck.

Please help wj32

Comment: @wj32 I have added my unsuccessful attempt in my original text for better clarity. It wasn't looking that great in comment section.

Comment: You didn't differentiate properly. Using the chain rule, you should get $Df(tx)x=kt^{k-1}f(x)$. Set $t=1$ to get $Df(x)x=kf(x)$.

Comment: how?? we have to differentiate with respect to x. and since *t* is a positive real no. $t^k$ is a constant (as k ∈ $\mathbb{R})$. So differentiating $f(tx)=t^kf(x)$ on both sides with respect to x would give $tf'(tx)=t^kf'(x)$ which in turn would imply $f'(tx)=t^{k-1}f'(x)$. this is what I got earlier too. Please if you know how to solve this problem give me some substantial hint. I am ready to work on your hints.

Comment: Differentiate with respect to $t$, not $x$.

Comment: thanx. doing what u said I finally got $k<f(x)/x  ,  x>$... now how to prove this is equal to kf(x)
...(I have edited my try in the main text as well)

Comment: @wj32 I am still waiting for your response. Please elaborate further. And also please give me some hint for part 2

Comment: @wj32 hey I am still hanging in the mid way. I hope you read this and solve this question for me. thank you.

Comment: anyone else at Math.SE, please help me

Comment: @wj32 the question itself mentions that $Df(x)$ is differentiating $f(x)$ with respect to $x$. So wont differentiating it with respect $t$ be wrong (as you suggested)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your questions can be solved just by the Chain Rule.

1). You already proved that if $f(tx)=t^kf(x)$, then $Df(x)\cdot x=kf(x)$. Now we need to show if $Df(x)\cdot x=kf(x)$, then $f(tx)=t^kf(x)$. Note that, from $Df(x)\cdot x=kf(x)$, we have $f(0)=0$ and
$$Df(tx)\cdot tx=kf(tx)$$
Now
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dt}\ln|f(tx)|\overset{chain \ rule}{=}D_{tx}\ln|f(tx)|\cdot\frac{d}{dt}(tx)=\frac{Df(tx)}{f(tx)}\cdot x=k\frac{1}{t}
\end{eqnarray*}
and hence 
$$\ln|f(tx)|-\ln|f(x)|=k\ln t$$
from which we have $f(tx)=t^kf(x)$.

2). Differentiating $f(tx)=t^kf(x)$ with respect to $x_i$ gives
$$ t\frac{\partial f(tx)}{\partial x_i}=t^k\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i} $$
or
$$ \frac{\partial f(tx)}{\partial x_i}=t^{k-1}\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i}. $$
So $\frac{\partial f(tx)}{\partial x_i}$ is homogeneous with degree $k-1$.

Comment: In the ques it is given that $Df(x)$ is derivative of $f$ at $x$ and NOT $t$. secondly, $Df(x) \cdot x$ is inner product i.e.$<\cdot,\cdot>$. So how are you differentiating inner products?