# is the complement of a cone union with origin still a cone?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

basically I want to ask is the epigraph of f(x) = - |x| a cone and I know the epigraph of f(x) = x is a cone. I didn't find it violate any part of the definition. But I wonder if it is still true in general.

Comment: Yes, but not necessarily a convex cone. Think of each ray as a single point. A ray is either in a cone or not.

Comment: I see. I was thinking about the top answer for this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466231/when-is-the-epigraph-a-convex-cone. After seeing your reply, I think it should eliminate the possibility that f(x) < 0, since the epigraph of f(x) = -|x| is not convex cone?

Comment: Correct, the epigraph of $|\cdot|$ is not convex. Not everyone defines a cone as a convex cone.

Comment: sorry but now im a bit confused. I was thinking the epigraph of f(x) = - |x| is not convex, and the author of the top answer did not constrain f(x) to have non-negative value (I followed the definition of positive homogeneous function from here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426801/positive-homogeneous), but I do think f(x) = |x| has a convex cone epigraph.

Comment: Dang, I meant $-| \cdot|$. Sorry.

Comment: no worries, thanks for sharing your thought :)

Comment: If by cone you mean convex cone, then the only way you can have a both a convex cone and its complement (with the origin)  be convex is if there is a hyperplane separating them.

Comment: Yeah that's why I didn't exclude the case where f(x) = 0 (only eliminate f(x) <0)

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by the $<0$ comment.

Comment: yeah you are right. I wanted to eliminate cases like f(x) = -x by define its codomain to be non-negative, but turns out that's not the right way. So need to rethink how to get rid of the functions with epigraph of the complement of a convex cone because i think by virtue of simply being postive homogeneous function doesn't guarantee that.